# Как сохранить изображение с PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сохранить изображение с PictureBox, но постоянно сохраняется только чёрное изображение или вылетает ошибка. Подскажите в чём проблема.

```
    Color CurrentColor = Color.Green;
    bool isPresed = false;
    Point CurrentPoint;
    Point PrePoint;
    Graphics g;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

    }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        pictureBox1.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
   private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isPresed = true;
        CurrentPoint = e.Location;
    }
   private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isPresed)
        {
            PrePoint = CurrentPoint;
            CurrentPoint = e.Location;
            for_paint();
        }
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        isPresed = false;
    }
    private void for_paint()
    {
            Pen p = new Pen(CurrentColor);
            g.DrawLine(p, PrePoint, CurrentPoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведённый код рисует на *графиксе* пикчабокса. Естественно, `Image` остаётся пустым.

Нужно создать графикс у `Image` и использовать его. Предварительно, нужно создать картинку нужного размера.

```
// эту строку удаляем
//g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

Ещё нужно обновлять `PictureBox`, чтобы внесённые в `Image` изменения отобразились:

```
private void for_paint()
{
    Pen p = new Pen(CurrentColor);
    g.DrawLine(p, PrePoint, CurrentPoint);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate(); // <--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пишу по памяти не проверяя код.
Попробуй так:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```